# Characteristic Variety of the Principal Symbol solves PDE system?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, pseudo-differential-operators, d-modules, microlocal-analysis

In the study of partial differential equations, it is often considered enough to analyze the principal symbols and their characteristic variety (see, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_of_a_differential_operator).  But there are easy examples for which this information is not enough.  Consider the two-dimensional system:
$$
(\partial+1)\phi(z,z')=0
$$
$$
(\partial+\partial')\phi(z,z')=0
$$
and,
$$
(\partial+z)\psi(z,z')=0
$$
$$
(\partial+\partial')\psi(z,z')=0.
$$
Both have the same principal symbols, namely, $p$ and $p+p'$, however, the first has the solution $\phi(z,z')=e^{z'-z}$, while the second has no solution (other than $\psi(z,z')=0$).

Clearly the two systems are distinct, and yet, it has been suggested that they  both  have one non-trivial solution within the context of the Kashiwara index theorem.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.  I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that they are only related *micro-locally*, but I can't see how this relates the solution space.

Comment: I'm not 100% confident, but if I recall correctly the principal symbol can only be used to construct a _parametrix_ i.e. an _approximate_ solution to each system.

Comment: It's true that it can be used to construct the parametrix, however, it supposedly can also be used in micro local analysis to determine the number of solutions to the above system.  So if you zoom in very close so that $z$ is approximately constant then both equations have a solution in a small enough neighborhood.  The idea, I think, is that these micro local solutions can be glued together but I can't see how that relates to the global solution, or if it does.